# Importing Large csv (2GB) into postgresql

Tags: windows, postgresql, csv, importerror

Hi guys am trying to import large csv file into a table with same defined fields and datatype in postresql, tried using COPY function in pgadmin4 and cmd(psql)
Ended up with the same error value too large.

.
Edit: I updated to postgresql 14 , now my error is :
ERROR:  out of memory
����:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073740884 bytes by 1071 more bytes.
����:  COPY BINDLL, line 1132693

Comment: Are you using Windows? I think there was a bug related to `psql.exe` not being able to read files bigger than 2GB which was fixed in Postgres 14.

Comment: Yes am on Windows. I'll update and check. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated to postgresql 14 , now my error is :
ERROR:  out of memory
����:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073740884 bytes by 1071 more bytes.
����:  COPY BINDLL, line 1132693